# How to notify React parent component when a specific child component is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a text input component that is wrapped with the following HOC component withSticky. withSticky determines if component is a sticky field. If it is I want the parent component to know. However, I want the parent component to update some state. All good but this also causes an infinite loop, because I place the callback inside the componentDidMount and setState causing all child components to re-render themselves - recreating the lifecylcle to no end. I don't want to look for these types of dynamic fields on every case because they're not always used.

I am not using redux just simple setState for now.

```
  import React from 'react';

const withSticky = (Component) => {
    return class extends React.Component {        
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            Component.displayName = 'withStickyContainer';
        }
    componentDidMount() {        
        const { fieldMetadata, onSticky,field} = this.props;
        //here fieldMetadata is not populated. therefore
        //fieldMetadata.IsSticky is undefined and onSticky never fires.
        const IsSticky = fieldMetadata.IsSticky;  
            console.log("is sticky mounted : ", this.props);
        if(IsSticky)
           onSticky(field.Id,field.Value);
    }
    render() {
     //wrong place to check field and trigger callback. This was calling infinite loop. Updated and moved to componentDidMount.
     //const { fieldMetadata, onSticky,field} = this.props;                        
     //const IsSticky = fieldMetadata.IsSticky;  
       // if(IsSticky)
         //  onSticky(field.Id,field.Value);
        console.log("field is sticky");          
        return (
            <div>
                <Component {...this.props}   />                    
            </div>
        );
    }
    }
};
export default withSticky;
```

Method inside Parent component that will be fired from the props of the child component.

```
    onSticky(fieldId,fieldValue){
    console.log("onsticky fired:",fieldId);
    console.log("field value : ", fieldValue);
    console.log("is field empty: ", _trim(fieldValue) ==='');
    const IS_EMPTY =_trim(fieldValue) ==='';
    const NOT_FOUND = -1;
    //lookup field Id and populate
    //check if lookup has value already if it does than update this field with value in lookup table
    //else take current value at set as initial sticky value.
    const {stickyFields} = this.state;        
    const foundField = _findIndex(stickyFields,f=> { f.Id == fieldId});
    if( foundField === NOT_FOUND && IS_EMPTY ){
        console.log("found nothing doing nothing");
        return;
    }else if(foundField === NOT_FOUND && !IS_EMPTY){
        //add to stickyFields lookup table.
        let stickyFieldsClone = deepClone(stickyFields);
        stickyFieldsClone.push({Id:fieldId,value:fieldValue});
        console.log("updating sticky fields lookup table");
        this.setState({stickyFields:stickyFieldsClone});
    }else if( foundField !== NOT_FOUND ){
        //grab value from lookup table and update field value 
    return;
    }        
}
```

In short, I have a datastructure in the parent component that keeps track of all these sticky fields. I don't want to search for them but i would like to be notified when a user uses them if at all. If they are used then keep track of the value inside the field.

Comment: Re-rendering doesn't call `componentDidMount`. Also, `IsSticky` is part of the props object, as far as I can see. So whether or not the child is sticky is readily available to the parentComponent without having to use a callback.

Comment: IsSticky is available in a normalized structure at the parent level. However, the sticky field are not used often and I did not want to traverse the datastructure looking for sticky fields if unnecessary.

Comment: @ChrisG removed callbacks from inside render and placed them in componentDidMount because you said that it is not called on re-render. That seemed to work however, now my props are not populated yet. I need access to those props values to distinguish the field type.

Comment: The props are populated from the very start, via the constructor. The error has to be somewhere else. Ideally you'll create a [mcve] on codesandbox or a similar site.

Comment: @ChrisG ok thanks for your insight. It enabled me to focus on why the props fieldMetadata was empty. I placed a few more console.logs and noticed that the fieldMetadata wasn't being finalized in setState till after this isSticky component was being mounted. Cheers.